# select value from jsonfield in queryset

Tags: django, postgresql

I have the following situation

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

`my_field` is a JSON field with the following structure:

```
{
    "name": "some name"
    "id": "some hash id"
}
```

I want to perform something like:
`MyModel.objects.values(my_field__name)`
which will be equivalent to the postgres query: `select my_field->>'name' from my_app_my_model`
 but i can't seem to get django to generate the wanted query. 
The error im getting is:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Join on 'my_field' not permitted.
```

The main goal here is to provide a list of strings called `fields` and run the following command:
`MyModel.objects.values(*fields)` so i think that raw sql solutions won't fit here. Custom Lookups are for the `WHERE` clause and i don't know of any equivalent for the `SELECT` clause.
Any thought on how this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT on JSONField with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379475/select-on-jsonfield-with-django)

Answer (score 5):

Currently `values` doesn't support json lookups. You can try to do it with [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra).

```
MyModel.objects.extra(select={'name':"my_field->>'name'"}).values('name')
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't use extra it might be deprecate for next versions as warning from django

Use RawSQL instead.

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(name=RawSQL("myfield->>'name'")).values('name').filter(<put your conditions here>)
```